# How to set user in NiFi0.7?

Tags: apache-nifi

how to set user in nifi 0.7,since in NiFi 0.7 UI we can able to see the user popup box but not the user add button[ScreenShot- NiFi 0.7 UI afor User page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te3GG.png)

Answer (score 0):

NiFi does not explicitly manage the creation or handling accounts but provides facilities to interact with PKI or various authority providers.  More information is available at the NiFi System Administrator's guide:  https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html

This provides instructions on using Kerberos or LDAP.  Additionally, the implementations are extensible which would allow folks to create additional interactions to provide user accounts.